# how to integrate @ngrx/store into Angular 5 project?

Tags: angular, ngrx-store-4.0

I am working on Angular 5 project with @ngrx/store.
The way to integrate ngrx/store into my application is following.

I have CoreModule which includes store. In the store directory, there are directories named search and user, and also reducer.ts and index.ts.

```
src - app - core - store - user (index, reducer, actions, selectors)
                         - search (index, reducer, actions, selectors)
                         - reducers.ts
                         - index.ts
```

reducers.ts

```
export interface AppState {
    search: Search;
    user: User;
}

export let AppReducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
    search: searchReducer,
    user: userReducer
};

export let AppActions = [SearchActions,UserActions];
```

index.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot('AppReducers')
  ],
  providers: [],
  declarations: [],
  exports: []
})

export class CoreStoreModule {};
```

To integrate CoreStoreModule into root module, I followed this way.

In the index.ts under core directory

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CoreStoreModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  exports: [
    CoreStoreModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ...APP_SERVICES,
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {

}
```

And app.module.ts of root module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    CoreModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I do not run into any error when compiling but reducer never works, nothing happens when action is dispatched. The libraries I am using are

```
"@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^5.1.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
```

There is not many documentation to provide information about how to use ngrx/store 5.. Could anyone give some information about it? How I can integrate @ngrx/store into Angular 5 project?

Answer (score 1):

You are providing a string instead of the actual variable here:

```
StoreModule.forRoot('AppReducers')
```

Change to:

```
StoreModule.forRoot(AppReducers)
```

Or if that doesn't work this might:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
  search: searchReducer,
  user: userReducer
})
```

Comment: Actually, I think i tried but will try again! 
Unfortunately, it still does not work.

Comment: Nothing happens when action dispatched.

Comment: @AnnaLee Can't help you further without a demo unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

What if you register you core module store as a feature module: `StoreModule.forFeature('core', reducers),`

And register an empty store in you app module:

```
export interface State {}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    ...
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```